# How to tile-print a PDF as a booklet?

Tags: pdf, printing, paper

I have a PDF document with credit-card-sized pages.  I am looking for a way to print this to an A4 sheet of paper, such that I can cut it up and staple it to form a booklet with the pages in the correct sequence.  This would be similar to the feature of MS Outlook to print an address book as a booklet, except that the page size isn't a tidy fraction of the paper size.

While Acrobat Reader has a booklet printing feature, it seems to support only the case of two pages per side.  If I were to try to use this then, wasted paper aside, there would be a big gap between the pages on the same sheet, which is unsuitable.

Can anyone advise of a good way I can do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* PDF viewers and printer drivers that are capable of printing multiple pages of a document per sheet of paper. For example, [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) has the dialog below to print multiple pages.

[image: PDF-XChange Print Dialog]

Other options on the printer *Properties* and/or application print dialog include borderless printing, margin sizes and centering.

Comment: How does this achieve "such that I can cut it up and staple it to form a booklet with the pages in the correct sequence"?  Furthermore, how would I eliminate the gap between pages that are going to be on the same sheet after cutting?